# Mayavi showing wrong object extent

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi, gis

I have a mosaic of Aster GDEM tiles which I have stitched together. When I plot the data with `plt.contourf(mosaic.lon1d, mosaic.lat1d, mosaic.elev, 40, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)` everything is in place and is shown correctly.
[image]

However, the following code:

```
fig = mlab.figure(figure='ICVM', bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0), size=(1024,786))
mlab.clf()

topo = mlab.surf(mosaic.lat1d, mosaic.lon1d, mosaic.elev, colormap='gist_earth', warp_scale=-1e-4)

mlab.axes(xlabel='lat.', ylabel='lon.')
mlab.outline()

mlab.view(-160, 125, 10, array([26.5,35.,-0.1168]))
mlab.roll(-90)
```

produces this plot, which is fine except for the the fact that the latitude goes from 24 to 29 instead of 29 to 34 like it should.
[image]

any ideas why that is? can I change this?

the following link will download the data (`lat1d, lon1d, elev`) as `.npy` file to be read in with `numpy.load`.
[download data zip file: http://goo.gl/nhCNFS](http://goo.gl/nhCNFS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that mayavi has problems if the array values are not increasing (Your lat1d data is decreasing).

If you reverse your lat1d and elev array you get a correct plot.

```py
fig = mlab.figure(figure='ICVM', bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0), size=(1024,786))
mlab.clf()

topo = mlab.surf(lat1d[::-1], lon1d, elev[::-1], colormap='gist_earth', warp_scale=-1e-4)

mlab.axes(xlabel='lat.', ylabel='lon.')
mlab.outline()
```

[image]